# Flycheck: How to disable c++11 Warnings?

Tags: flycheck, c++

I am using flycheck with its defaults to write modern C++ code.  I frequently get warnings such as:

`extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11`

when using modern features.

Can somebody tell me the best way to disable the warnings related to c++11 or c++14?

Comment: See the author's own answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30964293/864684).

Comment: Ah, I didn't see that post. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From @lunaryorn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30964293/864684):

> Flycheck provides the option `flycheck-gcc-language-standard` for this purpose. You should not set it globally, because that will break checking of C files, but you can set it from `c++-mode-hook` with the following code in your init file:

```el
(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook (lambda () (setq flycheck-gcc-language-standard "c++11")))
```

> However, I would recommend against this. Instead, use [Directory Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Directory-Variables.html) to configure the language standard per project.